# AS3 SWFAddress back button doesn't work in Safari 5.03 on Mac?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swfaddress

I have implemented SWFAddress 2.4, it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox on Mac. But in Safari 5.0.3 on Mac, the back button doesn't trigger the AddressChangeEvent. Deep linking works on Safari, just the back button doesn't.

Anyone have encountered this? Is it a bug and is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: as long as i can remember there have been issues fixed for Safari, only to be broken again when Apple updated the software.  you might find more concreate answer on the SWFAddress forum.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep on eye on that!

Comment: Any luck on this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope nothing, it seems to be a bug, I posted my question here and others seem to have problems with this as well: http://www.asual.com/blog/swfaddress/swfaddress-24.html

Comment: +1 There's still no solution for this is it ?